# Angular2 ComponentRouter prevent automatic component reuse

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html states

> ... By default, the router reuses a component instance when it re-navigates to the same component type without visiting a different component first. The parameters can change between each re-use...

but there is no hint how to change this default-behavior.

Is it possible to prevent the re-use?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported. There are plans to add support for some configurability in one of the next versions.

See also the discussion in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9811

That's now fixed by https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13124

See also https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx

Comment: thx, didn't see that one. so the documentation is wrong. There is no default, and no one can garantie that the param will never change because of deeplinking.

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: But that's a strategy to reuse but not to prevent the reuse for in params change. Are there any ways to achieve this?

Comment: I'm sure you can build a reuse strategy that does not reuse at all. I didn't try myself yet though. There is a situation where the route is different and the component should be reused (not reuse is the default) and the other is where the route stays the same but a parameter changed (defaults to reuse) where a custom reuse strategy should allow to also change that behavior. That's just what I remember from discussions to related GitHub issues.

Comment: The article from softwarearchitekt is kinda hard to understand for a beginner like me. I guess it's worth testing it out and do some trial and error with it. Thanks!

Comment: I know. I hope they will add a tutorial or cookbook  to http://angular.io