# How to update the view after changing the model in Angular2 by using this._router.navigate()

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular, angular-ui-router

I have 2 page who use the same template, I want to reload the template when I go from the page2 to page1 by using this._router.navigate().
the page2 use the page1 as a directive,

I want to do that 
let link = "/contrat/" + num

this._router.navigate(link)

and be equivalent to a window.location.href

I want to force the template to reload.
thank's

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786246/angular2-componentrouter-prevent-automatic-component-reuse/38786303#38786303

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: I add a code to explain

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little confusing but it looks like you syntax may be wrong. It should look something like this...

```
this.router.navigate(['page2']);
```

and make sure you define that path within a RouterConfig, for example

```
{path: 'page2', component: page2Component},
```